# Laravel recursive relations and returning $this

Tags: php, laravel, recursion, relationship

I have navbar with unknown levels of industries which can have child industries and I want to write recursive relationship to get the top one and show it as Category. I tried this:

```
public function category()
{
    if($this->parent_id == 0){
        return $this;
    } else {
        $this->parent_industry->category();
    }
}
```

But I keep getting 
**LogicException: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation**

How to write recursive relationship and return **$this**?

Comment: you can try creating relations within the same model.. I am assuming like a office table you will have something like employee_id and manager_id in the table so you may write 2 functions in the office model for the belongsTo and hasMany() and this may work ( I have done similar thing in rails and it works and this may work in Laravel as well)

Comment: If you call the function like this: `$var->category();` and not as an attribute `$var->category;`, it should work as it is now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this relations:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\MenuItem', 'parent_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\MenuItem', 'parent_id');
}

public function getRoot()
{
    $cur = $this;
    while ($cur->parent) {
        $cur = $cur->parent;
    }
    return $cur;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do this in an easy rather than using while

```
public function children()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\MenuItem', 'parent_id');
}

public function parent()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\MenuItem', 'parent_id');
}

public function root()
{
    if ($this->parent)
        return $this->parent->root();

    return $this;
}
```

Using recursion it is much simpler.

Hope this helps.